# Is it OK to downvote because I don't like a guy/gal?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, serial-voting, behavior, code-of-conduct

There is this guy that was rude to me in my questions, so he downvoted my question. And then added a rude comment. So I replied back and back and forth it became a heated argument. So I want to ask is it OK if I go to his page and downvote all of his questions as now I hated him. I intend to do this daily. Is it OK?

Comment: Rude comments have a different reply link. It is confusingly called *flag* but works way more effective as a reply then any other option. It does offer a textbox for cases where extra venting is needed.

Comment: "replied back and back and forth" is never a good thing to do in that case.

Comment: **Downvotes has nothing to do with being nice**. If you think you're serial downvoted, just flag.

Comment: Anyway... fortunately you came to meta and ask instead of just do it and get some "friendly reminder" from diamond moderators.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> So I want to ask is it OK if I go to his page and downvote all of his questions as now I hated him.

**NO**, Don't take revenge 
 it's meaningless to downvote all his posts.

> There is this guy that was rude to me in my questions, then added a rude comment

You need to flag that comments as **rude or abusive**

> now I hated him

**Calm down**  and read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Answer (score 23):

Let's start here...

> There is this guy that was rude to me in my questions, so he downvoted my question.

You don't know if they downvoted you.  Full stop.  Even if they claim they did, there's no way to prove it.

Now, to the main point - if they were rude to you, flag their comment and let a moderator deal with it.  Downvotes aren't weapons; they're a way to help determine the usefulness of a question or answer, and nothing more.  You can't use a vote to "get revenge" or exact some kind of justice on someone.

Disagreements happen, but you can take steps to not let it get heated, too.  Just walk away from the situation and let it deescalate.

Comment: I totally downvoted this.

Comment: it is very easy for anyone to see that @TinyGiant did that

Answer (score 8):

One other point revenge downvoting is [not acceptable behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) on the site and doing this persistently, i.e. daily, is a fast track to getting [suspended](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/).

> When a single user continually votes (up or down) on many of your
>   posts within a short period of time, the system considers these votes
>   to be invalid and removes them. This could happen for a variety of
>   reasons, such as a user finding a user's great answer and visiting all
>   of their posts to upvote them, or a user getting into an argument with
>   another user and downvoting their posts indiscriminately in revenge.
>   No matter the cause, this sort of systematic targeted voting is not
>   considered normal behavior and the system will not allow it.
>
> If such a voting pattern continues to happen between two users
>   mutually or from one user towards another, or otherwise falls outside
>   of normal voting patterns, moderators and/or developers may
>   investigate the matter; intentionally voting merely to reduce or
>   inflate another user's reputation is considered abuse.